# How to call a SigV4 authroized API Gateway from Java Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a java Lambda that receives S3EventNotification.

Now I need to make an API Gateway request which is authorized with AWS_IAM.

Lambda has IAM Role with permissions to call the API Gateway. With this, is it enough to just call the Api Gateway similar to axios request ?

I have seen examples for Node/python Lambda where using axios/fetch package, api gateway is being called but I don't see any Java examples.

Can some one please share the solution in java.

Comment: `What did you try?`